# How can I get data of logged in user from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I need help in this code.

How can I fetch logged in user data from firebase database?

These are my codes:

```
public void getUserInfo(){
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mUserDatabase = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("users");
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mUserDatabase.child(userID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange( com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot datasnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : datasnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                String firstname = user1.getFirstName();
                String secondname = user1.getSecondName();
                String email = user1.getEmail();
                String enrollment = user1.getEnrollnumber();
                String branch = user1.getBranch();
                String college = user1.getCollege();

                First_name.setText(firstname);
                Second_name.setText(secondname);
                tx_Email.setText(email);
                Enroll_number.setText(enrollment);

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
            /*
             * You may print the error message.
             **/
        }
    });

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: My best guess answer is below. If that isn't the cause of the problem: 1) add the actual problem to your question. It is unclear now what doesn't work about the code you shared. 2) add the JSON at `/users/$uid` to your question (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you're attaching a listener to the data of a single user. That means that you don't need to loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` in `onDataChange`.

So:

```
public void onDataChange( com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    User user1 = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

    String firstname = user1.getFirstName();
    String secondname = user1.getSecondName();
    String email = user1.getEmail();
    String enrollment = user1.getEnrollnumber();
    String branch = user1.getBranch();
    String college = user1.getCollege();

    First_name.setText(firstname);
    Second_name.setText(secondname);
    tx_Email.setText(email);
    Enroll_number.setText(enrollment);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, in my case my database in firebase is called "Users", with and userID is the id of each user, using this userID i filter the data of each user example (name, email...etc)

You need to write a for to iterate all fields and after that get the position that you need, example position[0] = name, position[1] = email...etc

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference idRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(userID);

final List<String> lstItems= new ArrayList<String>();
for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String values = (String) ds.getValue();
    lstItems.add(values);
}

Log.d(TAG, "NAME: " + lstItems.get(0).toString());
Log.d(TAG, "EMAIL: " + lstItems.get(1).toString());
```

and to print them

```
email = lstItems.get(0).toString();
name = lstItems.get(1).toString();
```

I hope it helps you